# beginSheetModalForWindow:_window (error undeclared identifier _window)

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode5

I created a class called TopMenuController and I want this to handle the IBActions for the Main Menu in the app, I have linked the class and have successfully used to output the below.

```
- (IBAction)about:(id)sender {
NSRunAlertPanel(@"string1", @"hi", @"OK", @"Cancel", @"other button");
}
```

But I would like to; and this is where I go wrong;

```
- (IBAction)about:(id)sender {
NSAlert *aboutPopUp = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"message1" 
defaultButton:@"OK"                  
alternateButton:@"cancel"
otherButton:@"otherbutton"
informativeTextWithFormat:@"hello"];

[aboutPopUp beginSheetModalForWindow:_Window 
modalDelegate:Nil 
didEndSelector:Nil    
contextInfo:Nil];
}
```

the beginSheetModalForWindow: needs to point to the main window which is from AppDelegate.h/m, and I can’t seem to reference the main window in the TopMenuController.m

if I set beginSheetModalForWindow:Nil <-- then i get a pop up window (but not the effect I was after)

The error is beginSheetModalForWindow:_Window (undeclared identifier)

Can anyone please help? Ive tried to google this, but I’m not sure what i should be googling?

Comment: How is _Window declared in your AppDelegate?  I can look at some stuff I have similar to this later if you are still having trouble.

Comment: Unrelated, but possibly important: How will you get `TopMenuController` into the responder chain?